# Upgrade to OwnCloud 5 without shell

Tags: owncloud

OwnCloud 5 is now out but the Updater addin doesn't offer to upgrade.

Does anyone familiar with the roadmap know if the updater is *going* to support the upgrade or if the major version change is out-of-scope of that project?

Otherwise, can you explain how to upgrade manually without having access to the shell?  I'm using some cheap hosting but it's working well so far.

- What preparations to take?
- What files to delete/keep?
- I keep the file repository root outside of the site root - anything special for that?
- I don't want to lose my username setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I saw on the mailing list somwhere that there will be an update from 4.5.x to 5.0.x...
I will post the link here if I find it again.
As far as I can remember, there will be some more time waiting for major bugs before the upgrade link to 5.0 is released - as there were quite a few in the 5.0.[0-2] releases, hopefully most of them are now resolved with the 5.0.3 release.

The basic upgrading process is described here: http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/maintenance/update.html#upgrade (use the "Upgrade" instructions!).
Most of your questions should be answered there, I'll try a quick summary:

- Preparations: Backup your data, owncloud files and database! Then
  follow the steps described there (it's not that many ;))
- Files to delete/keep: from the owncloud directory you can delete everything
  except for the config directory (and possibly the data directory, but
  you say you got that outside of the owncloud dir - if you mean what's
  configured with the "datadirectory" setting by that, then you
  probably don't even have a data folder anyway
  It should be no problem to copy the files via FTP, you don't need shell access.
- file repo outside of root: Should be considered automatically in the upgrade,
  all the settings will be kept!